# Sample nginx Dockerfile have an issue

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dockerfile

now days I am learning docker and I have created below dockerfile but browser not showing any sample html page

> > you refer below all details..

[root@localhost Apps]# cat Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y nginx
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

[root@localhost Apps]# docker build -t webs:nginx .

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/5 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 1d622ef86b13
Step 2/5 : RUN apt update
 ---> Running in 85fb0cb68eea

Removing intermediate container ae8ea9809c2b
 ---> be56c9ac472a
Step 4/5 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 5dac0da2fa9e
Removing intermediate container 5dac0da2fa9e
 ---> f97303ca1835
Step 5/5 : CMD `["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`
 ---> Running in 8d8019a327c6
Removing intermediate container 8d8019a327c6
 ---> afb3bdc37efa
Successfully built afb3bdc37efa
Successfully tagged webs:nginx

-------------------------------------------- Image Created -------------------------------
```

[root@localhost Apps]# docker images

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
webs                nginx               afb3bdc37efa        2 minutes ago       154MB
----------------------------------------HTML FILE--------------------------------------------------
```

[root@localhost ApacheWebserver]# ll

```
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 182 May  8 08:18 Index.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 195 May  8 08:22 My.html
```

[root@localhost ApacheWebserver]# `pwd`

```
/home/test/ApacheWebserver
---------------------- Run Image ---------------------------------------------------------
docker run --name mynginx1 -p 80:80 -v /home/test/ApacheWebserver:/var/www/html -d  webs:nginx
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what URL are you trying to access? what's the error that you get?

Comment: This site can’t be reached ip [* * * *] refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED I am getting above error I have checked firewall also 8080 port is open this is simple dockerfile example not sure why it is not working  >>   firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 8080:tcp
success

Comment: show output of running `docker ps`    then what url did you use in your browser to connect to this container ?   did you run  `docker inspect xxx` using container-id for xxx to show the IP of container ?  then its url would be  `http://yyy:80`     where yyy is that IP

Comment: You are mapping port  80 in the docker run command, not port 8080. If you want port 8080, use `-p 8080:80`

Comment: yes now it is working

Comment: docker run --name mynginx1 -p 8080:80 -v /home/test/ApacheWebserver:/usr/share/nginx/html/ -dit mywebserver:nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you are mapping port `80` to your host's port `80` but you are trying to access `localhost:8080` from the browser.

You should access `localhost:80` instead.